# Is there a penalty for death in Dragon Age Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

The title should be self-explanatory. If you die in Dragon Age Inquisition, as in all party members die, do you loose anything? Experience, gold, gear, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You're automatically prompted to reload from the last checkpoint, and will have everything you had at said checkpoint.

It's as close to a non-penalty as it gets -- the only downside is you have to start the fight that killed you all over again.